# Design of Appplication to handle task

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, architecture, task-queue

Problem Statement:-

I have to design an application to handle Tasks. In this Task are created by the scheduler at regular interval. The task must be pushed to queue for further processing and persisted in the database. Users can view and reschedule the task.

How should I approach the problem to design the system.

Comment: If you need help getting started, there's a blog post [here](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html) with some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would recommend either start by writing down in "sudo code" what you want the application to do or by creating a process diagram of a user creating a task and include steps describing what the system should do.  Maybe before either of those, a good place to start is in a brainstorming session.  I usually like to start with the five "W"s (okay, and I added an "H" at the end, but that doesn't roll off the tounge very well).  The five "W"s are **Who**, **What**, **Why**, **When**, **Where**, and **How**.

- Who will use the application?  Regular people?  Doctors?  Lawyers?  Teachers?
- What do users need the application to do?
- Why do users need the application to do those things?
- When will users use the application?  While they are at work?  While they are driving a car or riding a bicycle?
- Where will users use the application?  On their mobile phones?  One their desktop or laptop computers?  On their tablets?  On a refrigerator?  (not joking on that last one, we have computers now on refrigerators)

I'm not sure if you want to build a web application, mobile app, or something else.  To answer your question better more specific information is needed.  But, in the mean time here's a tutorial on how to write an application to handle tasks (a todo app), which is written in Java.

https://youtu.be/RXtj4TxMmW0

And here's a tutorial showing how to create a to do app using Django:

https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/how-to-build-a-todo-app-with-django-17afdc4a8f8c

And here's a tutorial showing how to create a to do app using React:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-simple-to-do-app-with-react

Another great tool to get you started is either a white board, or just a bunch of paper, a pencil, and lots of erasers.  Sometimes the easies way to begin is just jotting down your ideas on paper.  Once the "creative juices" start flowing and you have so many ideas on paper that you are running out of room, it sometimes helps to group similar ideas together.  It sometimes then makes sense to combine ideas together to form one bigger idea.  Then try to identify of all the things you want your app to do, which are the most important and put them in order of priority.

Out of your brainstorming try to figure out what `data` is needed in order to make your application work.  For example, a todo app might have a `ToDo` data element.  It might also have a `User` element, which each `ToDo` element might be owned by.  For each data element, also called an `Model`, `Table`, or a `Entity` (all three of these things are the same, just different names) try to figure out what `attributes` are needed in each model.  For example,  the `User` model might have the attributes: `username`, `password`, `email_address`, `first_name`, and `last_name`.  The `ToDO` model might have the attributes: `name`, `description`, `is_complete`, and `completed_date_time`.

And maybe look around at other ToDo applications to see how they work and get more ideas.  Best of luck with your ToDo app!

Comment: My question is how to process task on the basis of priority. I want to implement solution in Java